# Есть ли в Python библиотека возвращающая текущее время из сети

Tags: python, библиотеки, бот, ntp

Требуется функция которая будет возвращать текущее время. Создаю бота, учусь. Хочу что-бы бот при определенной команде возвращал текущее время определенного часового пояса из сети. К примеру:

```py
def time(ctx, arg):
    if arg == "Msc":
        await ctx.send("Тут то самое время")
```

Comment: Посмотрите про NTP, вероятно это то что вам нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно вам поможет [эта](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/) библиотека

Comment: Небольшой пример использования смотрелся бы очень удачно